# JQuery slideToggle() doesn't slide up nav in mobile

Tags: jquery

I have built a navigation that is responsive it works, but my question is when in mobile state, when link is clicked then navigation doesn't slide back up. I made a second js file that accomplished this but it happens on desktop size as well

here it is http://www.methodzerodesign.com/nav/index.html

I have latterly spent the last 8 hours looking for the answer but to no avail.

here is the html:

```
<span class="menu-trigger"><img src="img/navIcon.png"></span>
<div class="navigation">
<ul class="navList">
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#webDesign">Web Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#reDesign">Redesign</a></li>
<li><a href="#ourWork">Our Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#choices">Site Choices</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function(){

        jQuery(".navigation").slideUp( 400, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display','');

        });
      });
    });
```

also looking for a good place to further learn js.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `nav-expanded` class in your html code. Besides, `.menu-trigger` is not visible. Please, Fix both and try it again,

Comment: I have no idea what that means, I was shown that nav-expanded was a css clear, and the menu-trigger is the little m on the top. that part works, what I was trying to do is when clicked on a menu item I wanted the menu to return to the normal state.

Comment: You need to use a valid class name when you call

Comment: - toggleClass()